# How to interpolate so that I can 'stretch' a 20-item array into a 30-item array, but keeping the total and the percentiles the same?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

If I have this numpy array:

```
x = np.array([10,20])
```

and I want to "stretch" it by doubling its size, I can very easily do it with

```
y = np.repeat(x,2)/2
```

and get

```
[5,5,10,10]
```

However, **what if I want to stretch it adding not 2 but an arbitrary number of periods?** It's as though I wanted to repeat by a non-integer number in the formula above.

The background to this is that I have an array which measures something over time - e.g. each element of the array is the distance covered in one period.

**I need to 'stretch' the array, e.g. calculate a new array where the same distance is covered in, say, 30 periods instead of 20.
I need the percentiles to be the same, so that the total distance covered is the same, the sum of the first 10 elements in the 1st array = the sum of the first 15 in the new array, etc.**

Linear interpolation is fine.

I have concocted something together with  `scipy.interpolate` but it seems a bit convoluted and I was wondering if there's a better way.
The steps are:

- I start from my array y I set x as the corresponding % index, so that
  the 1st item is 1/length and the last = 100%
- I add a zero at the
  beginning ox both x and y (to avoid an interpolation below range error)
- I interpolate the cumulative sum
- I use the
  interpolated function to calculate a 'stretched' array

The code is this.
**EDIT**: I have looked into @eliadl 's answer. It is very close to mine, but not 100% identical. It's not clear to me what is driving the difference - any insight would be welcome!

I have put together the code below to show the differences. My code achieves what I had in mind: if the original array had 4 items and the new 10, and the CDF (cumulative distribution function) = 40% at the second item, then the CDF must = 40% for the 5th item of the new array, etc.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import seaborn
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
sns.set(style='darkgrid')

def my_stretch(inp, s):

    y  = inp
    x = np.arange(1, len(y) +1  ) / len(y)

    y_2 = np.hstack([0,y])
    x_2 = np.hstack([0,x])

    f_int = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(x_2 , np.cumsum(y_2) )

    x_new = np.arange(0, len(y) + s + 1 ) / ( len(y) + s )
    y_new_cum = f_int(x_new)
    y_new = np.diff(y_new_cum)

    return y_new

def your_stretch(inp,s):
    x = np.arange(y.size)
    x_stretch = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], num = x.size + s )
    y_stretch = np.interp(x_stretch, x, y)
    y_stretch *= y.sum() / y_stretch.sum()
    return y_stretch

def cdf(x):
    return np.cumsum(x) / x.sum()

y = np.array([20,10,8,6,4,2])
s = 3
my_s = my_stretch(y,s)
your_s = your_stretch(y,s)

cdf_orig = cdf(y)
cdf_my = cdf(my_s)
cdf_your = cdf(your_s)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1)

sns.lineplot( np.arange(1,len(my_s) + 1 ) / len(my_s) , cdf_my, label = 'mine', marker='o', ax = ax[0] )
sns.lineplot( np.arange(1,len(your_s) + 1)/len(your_s) , cdf_your, label = 'yours', marker ='o', ax = ax[0] )
sns.lineplot( np.arange(1,len(y) + 1 ) / len(y) , cdf_orig, label = 'original', ax = ax[0] )

ax[1].plot( my_s , label = 'mine' , marker='o' )
ax[1].plot(your_s, label = 'yours',  marker='o')

ax[0].set_xlabel('% position (the last item in the array = 1 ↑')
ax[0].set_ylabel('cumulative distribution function')
ax[1].set_xlabel('item in the array ↑')
ax[1].set_ylabel('value')
ax[1].legend()
```

Comment: Does my answer answer your question well?

Comment: Sorry, I have been busy on something else but I will look into it soon. Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: Your approach produces a result that's very close to mine but not identical. I have edited my original question to show the differences. Any insight on what's  causing the differences would be welcome! Thanks again for taking the time!

Comment: No insights I'm afraid. Also please note that's a new question based on my answer to *"How to interpolate..?"* that you've originally asked. You may want to consider posting it as a separate question. And if my answer satisfies your *original* question, please consider accepting it. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I would not consider yours a fully satisfactory answer. Eg if you start from [10,8] and add 2 more items, my approach produces [5,5,4,4], yours produces [5, 4.6,4.3,4]. The sum is the same, but I think the key difference is that I am interpolating between each point, whereas you are interpolating a single straight line that passes through all the points. With more oddly shaped curves, the difference would be greater and your approach would not produce what I need. Thanks a lot anyway for taking the time - it was interesting to look at an alternative approach.

Comment: I am *"interpolating a single straight line that passes through all the points"* because that's what you asked for in your question: *"Linear interpolation is fine."* My approach [5, 4.6, 4.3,4] seems to fully satisfy your criteria, as opposed to your approach [5, 5, 4, 4]. Please reconsider.

Comment: I was unclear. I meant linear interpolation between one point and the next, not the new curve to be a straight line. Like I said in the initial question, I need the percentile to be the same. So if I have a 12-element array where the first 4 elements sum to 40% of the total, and I extend it to a 15-element array, then the first 5 need to sum to the same 40% (because 4/12 = 5/15). I need the new curve to have a shape as similar as possible to the starting one - a straight line doesn't do that. I am sorry for the misunderstanding, and I really appreciate your taking the time!

Comment: I see what you mean. It seems that you're more familiar with interpolation methods, as I'm unfamiliar with interpolating the cumsum like you have. On another note, notice my curve creates a straight line only when starting with [10,8] because two dots create a line. However when I start with [20,10,8,6,4,2] then the curve I get is *not* a straight line: `np.diff(y_stretch)  # [-4.2, -2.8, -.85, -.85, -.85, -.85, -.85, -.85]`

Answer (score 2):

Using [**`np.interp`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) and [**`np.linspace`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html):

```
y = np.array([20, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2])
stretch_by = 1.5

x = np.arange(y.size)  # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

x_stretch = np.linspace(
    start=x[0], stop=x[-1], num=x.size * stretch_by,

)  # [0, 0.625, 1.25, 1.875, 2.5, 3.125, 3.75, 4.375, 5]

y_stretch = np.interp(x_stretch, x, y)  # [20, 13.75, 9.5, 8.25, 7, 5.75, 4.5, 3.25, 2]
y_stretch *= y.sum() / y_stretch.sum()  # normalize y_stretch.sum() to y.sum()

print(f"{y}'s sum is {y.sum()}\n")
print(f"{y_stretch}'s sum is {y_stretch.sum()}")
```

Output:

```
[20 10  8  6  4  2]'s sum is 50

[13.51351351  9.29054054  6.41891892  5.57432432  4.72972973  3.88513514
  3.04054054  2.19594595  1.35135135]'s sum is 50.0
```